# Remove this conditional structure or edit its code blocks so that they're not all the same in sonar bug how to handle

Tags: ios, objective-c, sonarqube

** The code was mentioned sonar bug in multiple class how to handle this  **

```
if ([orderTypeS isEqualToString:kOrderDelivery]) {
            [dateSetFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"];
            checkHolidayDate  = [dateSetFormat dateFromString:checkHolidyString];
            if (!checkHolidayDate) {
                [dateSetFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
                checkHolidayDate  = [dateSetFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
            }else{
                
            }
        }else{
            [dateSetFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"];
            checkHolidayDate  = [dateSetFormat dateFromString:checkHolidyString];
            if(!checkHolidayDate){
                checkHolidayDate  = [dateSetFormat dateFromString:checkHolidyString];
            }else{
               
            }
```

Comment: Well ... the message gives you a clue. The code is the same so why do you need an if to separate them. Either combine them or take away the if. It is like ```if( cond ) { xxx; } else { xxx; }``` No matter what the condition may be, you ```xxx``` so it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below link and solved the issue.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/objective-c

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below link. basically when you write same statement in if and else block then this error occurs.

https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/RSPEC-3923.